# Trigger Email based on any text in Specific Column

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, return-value

Trying to trigger to send email when anything is put into column C. With currect script it will work just fine if I put TEST in any row column C works great. I need it to trigger if anything is put into anyrow column C. Is there a wildcard so to speak for anything entered?

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
  if ((e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "TEST")) return; 
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
  let job = rData[0][1];
  let req = rData[0][0];
  let item = rData[0][2];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
   var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Requestors").getRange("B2:B");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
  
  let msg = "Job # = " + job + " \nRequestor = " + req + " \nItem Requested = " + item + "  \nDate & Time Requested " + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Raw Material Request", msg) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your expected result of `I need it to trigger if anything is put into anyrow column C.`, in this case, how about using `isBlank()`? When this is reflected in your script, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
if ((e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "TEST")) return;
```

#### To:

```
if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.range.isBlank()) return;
```

- By this, when a value is put into column "C", the script below this if statement is run.

#### Reference:

- [isBlank() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

Comment: @Jim Spalding About `That worked perfectly, Thank You` welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Jim Spalding Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.